# Update from external storage disabled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4, rom-update

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (N910a), and the WiFi doesn't work. I think it's because it has an old firmware version, so I tried to update it, but when in recovery and trying to update from the SD card, it says "Update from external storage is disabled." the same thing happens with adb.

Comment: Did you try through Odin/Heimdall?

Comment: And please check if the WiFi MAC adress is still present.

Comment: Yes, there is a mac address, but the WiFi button is grayed out...

Comment: Do you have network connection? Does the Bluetooth work?

Comment: The Bluetooth works, and it doesn't let me connect it to wifi

Comment: Did you try the solution described in my answer?

Comment: The download link doesn't work

Comment: I flashed another rom and the WiFi worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flashing the stock firmware with Odin. This should work.
Stock firmware download [here](http://androidromupdate.com/install-n910aucu2doi2-att-galaxy-note-4-sm-n910a-official-android-5-1-1-firmware/)
Odin flasher download [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-odin-downloader-versions)

- Open Odin
- Unzip the firmware zip file
- Click on APP and browse to where you extracted the firmware zip file
- Boot the phone to Download mode (Volume down + Power button)
- Connect the phone and click Start.